# iphone app - UDP

Tags: iphone, udp

Is it possible for an iphone to send UDP messages through an IP on port 3330?

Thanks!
Elijah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. You can open an UDP connection with BSD sockets API.

Check out these functions:

1. socket()
2. connect()
3. bind()
4. send()
5. recv()
6. sendto()
7. recvfrom()

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the  [AsyncUdpSocket Class](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/browse/trunk/AsyncUdpSocket.h) from [cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/). This should make things easier.